# can you explain the for loop in this program, it gives me the result i want but! i took it from internet not fully aware of what it does

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

```
T =[{
    "customername" : "A",
    "type" : "software",
    "orderhistory": [{
    "items" : "item 1",
    "price" : "20"
    },
    {
    "items" : "item 2",
    "price" : "10"

        }
    ]
},
{ "customername" : "B",
    "type" : "Accountant",
    "orderhistory": [{
    "items" : "item 1",
    "price" : "20"
    },
    {
    "items" : "item 2",
    "price" : "10"

        }
    ]
  }
 ]
for item in T:
    print("customername: {}\n type:{}\n orderhistory:{}\n" .format(item['customername'], item['type'],
                                                                   item['orderhistory']))
```

Comment: What specifically about it are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T consists of two dictionaries which consist of customername, type, orderhistory(which is a list of dictionaries).

In the for loop, you are printing the contents of your dictionary T using format() function where {} means some element will be present there. Either you can represent is plainly as {} or you can number them as {0}, {1} , {2},.....

In the format(), all the elements you want to print in {} should be placed in order of printing.

But, you should change it to T[0]["customername"] to access the value associated with customername in first dict since it is a dict inside a list.

Answer (score 0):

This program would firstly iterate through those 2 dictionaries that are present inside the list ( only because of the for loop). This means that the variable named `item` would take the following values sequentially:

1. Value of `item` first time

```
{
    "customername" : "A",
    "type" : "software",
    "orderhistory": [{
    "items" : "item 1",
    "price" : "20"
    },
    {
    "items" : "item 2",
    "price" : "10"

        }
    ]
}
```

2. Value of `item` the second time:

```
{ "customername" : "B",
    "type" : "Accountant",
    "orderhistory": [{
    "items" : "item 1",
    "price" : "20"
    },
    {
    "items" : "item 2",
    "price" : "10"

        }
    ]
  }
```

So whenever the variable named `item` gets these values, then the part of the code

```
print("customername: {}\n type:{}\n orderhistory:{}\n" .format(item['customername'], item['type'],
                                                                   item['orderhistory']))
```

Gets executed. So to summarize, all the for loop does is to give the variable named `item` the above-mentioned values and then to run the print command every time variable `item` gets a new value.

You may learn about for loop in detail over here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZvaDa8eT5s

If you are not able to understand the print statement, then you may know more about it over here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fy10ci10R_g

Comment: @Abdaldaim Are you able to understand this now, or should I write more?